# JAVA Package won't import even though it was declared

Tags: java, import, compiler-errors, package

I'm trying to compile a program but it always displays an error that my package cannot be found but its properly declared (i think)

The exact [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGLTS.png) im getting

Here's the beginning part of the code of the program im packaging:

```
package domain;
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int empNO;
  private int age;
```

and here's the beginning of the program Im importing it into:

```
package test;
import domain.*;

public class TestPerson {
     public static void main (String args[]) {
```

this is essentially the [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6h3H.png) of the project:

Comment: Looks like your whole project structure is wrong. How do you compile the classes?

Answer (score -1):

Try `import com.companyName.department.domain`. I think its because you didn't specify the whole path of the package you were trying to import.

Comment: doesn't work now it says `package com.companyName.department does not exist`

Comment: Try import com.companyName.department.domain.*; and if that dosent work try import com.companyName.department.domain.Person